# Show content under a SliverChildBuilderDelegate

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to show widgets (for example a `SliverToBoxAdapter` or a normal `Container`) underneath a `SliverChildBuilderDelegate`? I have a condition that turns on the SliverList and there can only be one parent widget for a condition, what would I need to wrap it in?

Code currently looks like:

```
lass Testaaa extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool hasData;

  const Testaaa({Key key, this.hasData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: DrawerSettings(),
      body: Container(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            AppBarSliver(),
            hasData
                ? SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (BuildContext context, int i) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text('cool'),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ) // I would like to put another Container here that
                    // scrolls with the bottom, underneath the SliverList
                : Container(
                    child: Text('no data'),
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: are you using CustomScrollView? or how does your code looks like?

Comment: @EdwynZN I've added some code... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like a work for the spread operator

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    AppBarSliver(),
    ...hasData
      ? <Widget>[
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int i) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('cool'),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(
              child: Text('End of the list'),
            ),
          ),
        ]
      : <Widget>[
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(
              child: Text('no data'),
            ),
          )
      ]
  ],
)
```

This way you're telling if hasData is true add all this widgets in the brackets (SliverList and SliverToBoxAdapter with Text 'End of the list') if false add all this other widgets (which is only a SliverToBoxAdapter)

Comment: Thanks @edwynZN, however when I do that I get `type 'List<Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'` EDIT: scratch that, I got it working. Thanks once again!